# Java Return Loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will find the longest ascending substring from the given numerical input.

(Eg. input = "1215678" output = "5678")

the return at the bottom of the loop isn't working: it says that it can't find the variable for asc in the return at the bottom.... what's wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ascending
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
{ 

    System.out.print("Enter a number = ");

    //scan the input
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String k = in.nextLine();



}

public static String itsAscending(String n) 
{

    int length = k.length();    

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {

        char first = k.charAt(i);       
        char next = k.charAt(i+1);      
        int f = (int)(first - 48);       
        int nx = (int)(next - 48);      

        String asc;
        String works = ""; 

        if (f<nx) 
        {

            works = works + k.substring(i, i+2);
            asc = works.substring(0, works.length()-1); 

        }

        else 
        {

            works = works + "";
            asc = works.substring(i, works.length()-1); 

        }
    }

return asc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `asc` within the `for` loop. Move it to the outside.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `asc` inside the for loop and its visible inside the loop only. If you want to access it outside the loop's scope then define it outside.

Comment: i moved it to under the int length = k.length(); however I get this message: variable increasing might not have been initialized

Comment: define it like: `String asc = null;`

Comment: then you should initialize it to "" ;)

Comment: thanks. that fixed that problem, however now when I run it and put in my numbers - it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a proper way to get help here. Update your question with your new code and describe expected vs real output.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise your variable `asc` outside for loop.

```
    public static String itsAscending(String n)
    {
    String asc = "";
```

---

Declare variable `k` or `public static String itsAscending(String k)`

---

Better if you call the method form `main` method

```
String k = in.nextLine();
itsAscending(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `asc` outside any loop or conditional statement.

```
public static String itsAscending(String n) 
{
    String asc = null;  
    // Rest of the method 
}
```